# Capture "error" object in HTTP get Response

Tags: google-cloud-platform, yaml, google-workflows, google-cloud-code

I have requirement to load data from BQ to PostGreSQL using GCP Workflows.

Basically i am doing a HTTP Post call to PostGreSQL and invoking "importContext" method to perfrom the import operation.

```
 steps:
- callImport:
    call: http.post
    args:
      url: ${"https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/v1/projects/" + projectid + "/instances/" + instance + "/import"}
      auth:
        type: OAuth2
      body:
        importContext:
          uri: ${file}
          database: ${databaseschema}
          fileType: CSV
          csvImportOptions:
            table: ${importtable}
            columns : [a,b,c,b]
    result: operation
```

In my flow i am calling HTTP GET method to check if the import operation is DONE or NOT , strangely in case of any ERROR while import the response is getting status code as DONE along with the Error tag in the body response which suppose to be status:ERROR .

Successful body Response:

```
{
   "body":{
      "endTime":"2023-07-26T12:15:55.629Z",
      "importContext":{
         "csvImportOptions":{
            "columns":[strings
            ],
            "table":"table_name"
         },
         "database":"postgres",
         "fileType":"CSV",
         "kind":"sql#importContext",
         "uri":"gs://workflow/2023-07-26000000000000.csv"
      },
      "insertTime":"2023-07-26T12:15:44.791Z",
      "kind":"sql#operation",
      "name":"af439df3-21ea-45b2-a92c-a4de00000024",
      "operationType":"IMPORT",
      "selfLink":"https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/v1/projects/",
      "startTime":"2023-07-26T12:15:45.027Z",
      "status":"DONE",
      "targetId":"pricing-dev-master",
      "targetLink":"https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/v1/projects/",
      "targetProject":"project-dev",
      "user":"sa@.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
   },
   "code":200,
   "headers":{
      "Alt-Svc":"h3=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000",
      "Cache-Control":"private",
      "Content-Length":"1179",
      "Content-Type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8",
      "Date":"Wed, 26 Jul 2023 12:16:00 GMT",
      "Server":"ESF",
      "Vary":"Origin, X-Origin, Referer",
      "X-Content-Type-Options":"nosniff",
      "X-Frame-Options":"SAMEORIGIN",
      "X-Xss-Protection":"0"
   }
}
```

Error response Body :

```
{
   "body":{
      "endTime":"2023-07-26T10:19:49.527Z",
      "error":{
         "errors":[
            {
               "code":"ERROR_RDBMS",
               "kind":"sql#operationError",
               "message":"generic::failed_precondition: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: \"2023-07-11\"\nCONTEXT:  COPY table_name, line 1, column id: \"2023-07-11\"\n"
            }
         ],
         "kind":"sql#operationErrors"
      },
      "importContext":{
         "csvImportOptions":{
            "table":"table_name"
         },
         "database":"postgres",
         "fileType":"CSV",
         "kind":"sql#importContext",
      },
         "uri":"gs://workflow/2023-07-26000000000000.csv"
      "insertTime":"2023-07-26T10:19:38.945Z",
      "kind":"sql#operation",
      "name":"375f1c18-c2ac-4b1e-800c-650f00000024",
      "operationType":"IMPORT",
      "selfLink":"https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/v1/projects/",
      "startTime":"2023-07-26T10:19:39.118Z",
      **"status":"DONE",**
      "targetId":"pricing-dev-master",
      "targetLink":"https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/v1/projects/",
      "targetProject":"project-dev",
      "user":"sa@.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
   },
   **"code":200**,
   "headers":{
      "Alt-Svc":"h3=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000",
      "Cache-Control":"private",
      "Content-Length":"1290",
      "Content-Type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8",
      "Date":"Wed, 26 Jul 2023 10:19:49 GMT",
      "Server":"ESF",
      "Vary":"Origin, X-Origin, Referer",
      "X-Content-Type-Options":"nosniff",
      "X-Frame-Options":"SAMEORIGIN",
      "X-Xss-Protection":"0"
   }
}
```

To handle this situtation i wanted to write a logic to make the workflow Fail in case of ERROR in import process. I tried to capture the body response in "maps" but then its not working. Can you please suggest is this the right way to append a map on every HTTP Get calls?

```
   - chekoperation:
        switch:
          - condition: ${operation.body.status != "DONE"}       
            next: wait
          - condition: ${"sql#operationError" in progress_Map} 
            raise: "Error in the load"
        next : completed    
    - completed:
        return: "done"
    - wait:
        call: sys.sleep
        args:
          seconds: 5
        next: getoperation
    - getoperation:
        call: http.get
        args:
          url: ${operation.body.selfLink}
          auth:
            type: OAuth2
        result: operation
        next: trackprogress
    # Creating Maps to add the response body into progress_Map 
    - trackprogress:
        assign:
        - progress_Map[file]: ${operation.body}
          raise : $(progress_Map)
    - returnoutput:          
        return: ${progress_Map}
        next: chekoperation
```

I have the below code to handle '''switch''' to control the exeution but somehow its not working.

```
    - chekoperation:
    switch:
      - condition: ${operation.body.status != "DONE"}  
        # Tried this as well
      #- condition: ${not("DONE" in progress_Map)}      
        next: wait
      - condition: ${"sql#operationError" in progress_Map} 
           
        raise: "Error in the load"
    next : completed
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no "status" key in the body in case of error, this condition will fail:

```
- condition: ${operation.body.status != "DONE"}
```

To prevent that you can have another condition (or replace it) at the top to check if that node is there like this:

```
- condition: ${"status" in operation.body == false}
```

Or was I getting something wrong?